# Basic Ruby questions

Tags: ruby

My understanding is that `checking` and `savings` are saved under `account_a` and `account_b`. Can someone explain what's happening in the last two lines?

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :balance
  def initialize(balance)
    @balance = balance
  end
end

class Transaction
  def initialize(account_a,account_b)
    @account_a = account_a
    @account_b = account_b
  end
  private
  def debit(account, amount)
    account.balance -= amount
  end
  def credit(account,amount)
    account.balance += amount
  end
  public
  def transfer(amount)
    debit(@account_a, amount)
    credit(@account_b, amount)
  end
end

savings = Account.new (100)
checking = Account.new (200)
trans = Transaction.new(checking, savings)
trans.transfer(50)
```

How do I print the value of `trans`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second to last line, you are initializing a new Transaction from your `checking` account to your `savings` account. Then in the last line, you are transferring 50.

You cannot print the value of trans because there is no value associated with it. You can print out the balance of your initialized accounts though, by calling `savings.balance` and `checking.balance`

Comment: Question? 
Am I initiating transaction from checking to savings or am I creating it?
and that 50 is transfered to which account?

Comment: Transaction is a class and you are creating an instance of it. The 50 is transferred from your checking (1st argument) to your saving (2nd argument). You can test this by running your code then running `savings.balance` and `checking.balance` to see the new balances.

Comment: Could you explain me whats happening at:
`def debit(account, amount)
    account.balance -= amount
  end`
cant I do `savings.debit` to check it?

Comment: You are creating a method called `debit` which has two arguments: `account` and `amount`. This will set the account instance object's balance to the current balance minus the amount passed in as a second argument.

Comment: Alex, you are doing your best to explain me...but I am not understanding anything at all. 
`savings = Account.new (100)
checking = Account.new (200)`

does it mean savings have balance of 100 and checking have balance of 200? please tell me I got that right?

Is this saving and checking connected to `@amount_a` and `amount_b`?

why is there a need to do savings.balance to find their value?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You are creating new Account instances, which takes a balance as an argument.

Comment: Is this saving and checking created by 'savings = Account.new' connected to @amount_a and amount_b? why is there a need to do savings.balance to find their value

Comment: No. The instance variables @amount_a and @amount_b are assigned by creating a new instance of the Transaction class. So when you call `trans = Transaction.new(checking, savings)`, the instance variables are assigned like so: `@amount_a = checking, @amount_b = savings`

Comment: Things are becoming very clear to me now. why do I have to do savings.balance to see their value...is there an alternate way?

Comment: There isn't an alternative to access the balance. The balance attribute (attr) is what stores the balance value in the Account class. You see where it says `attr_accessor :balance`? This allows you to set/get the balance of an Account instance.

Comment: Make lots of sense! you are a Yoda! I think I am getting @account_1 and actual savings getting mixed up....STUPID ME!

Comment: Glad to help! Since you're new here, please don't forget to accepted the answer which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: Its telling me that I need 15 rep to put this up :( how can I do this?

Comment: One last question...
`amount` in `def transfer(amount)`
how come we can insert a value to it without doing the `attr_accessor` thing?

Comment: You could simply create setter/getter methods in the Account class. `attr_accessor` is a shortcut for creating setter/getter methods for attributes.

Comment: How come we were able to insert the value 50 without having the setter/getter in it?

Comment: Like I said, `attr_accessor` is a shortcut for creating the setter/getter methods. It creates a method called `balance` which will read the value of that attribute and a method called `balance=` which will set the value of that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `trans` using `Transaction.new` then references to `checking` and `savings` are stored inside the transaction object as `@account_a` and `@account_b`

The `transfer` method calls `debit` with `@account_a` and `credit` with `@account_b` so decreasing the balance of `a` by the amount and increasing the balance of `b` by the same amount, in effect transferring from checking to savings.

Comment: The checking and savings associated with @account_a and @account_b. are they same as `savings=Account.new`?